# Missing page number in specific page

Tags: numbering, packages

I have the Acknowlgwmnet section that does not show the page numbering. So the Dedication starts with iii, then Acknowlgment no number, then abstract had v page number. So it counts, but it doesnot show the page number. Here is my code

```
\documentclass[botnum, fleqn]{unmeethesis}
                 % OR
% Use the following specification for TOP page numbering:
% \documentclass[fleqn]{unmeethesis}
\usepackage{amsthm,cite,graphicx,,booktabs,lipsum,color,bm,caption,subcaption,soul}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont,tikz,paralist,multirow,amssymb,stmaryrd}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter


\title{}

\author{ }

\degreesubject{ }

\degree{}

\documenttype{DISSERTATION}

\previousdegrees{
}

\date{December, \thisyear}

\maketitle

\end{dedication}

\begin{acknowledgments}
\end{acknowledgments}
```

Comment: unrelated but do not use `\usepackage{epsfig}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle    because I have eps figures.

Comment: Where could we obtain the `unmeethesis.cls` document class? We can't test your code without it.

Comment: @Karen You can convert eps figures to PDF format and then use them directly. `epsfig` is obsolete way for including figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A command (`\clearpage`) is missing from the `acknowledgements` environment definition that prevents the page number from appearing when the `botnum` option is used.

Try this code with a redefinition of that environment using a patch.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[botnum, fleqn]{unmeethesis}  
\usepackage{amsthm,cite,graphicx,,booktabs,lipsum,color,bm,caption,subcaption,soul}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont,tikz,paralist,multirow,amssymb,stmaryrd}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
    
%%******************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\endacknowledgments}{\clearpage}{}{}
%%******************* 
    
\begin{document}    

\frontmatter

\title{}

\author{}

\degreesubject{}

\degree{}

\documenttype{DISSERTATION}

\previousdegrees{}

\date{December, \thisyear}

\maketitle

\begin{dedication}

\end{dedication}

\begin{acknowledgments}
Some text 

\end{acknowledgments}

%
\maketitleabstract %(required even though there's no abstract title anymore)

\begin{abstract}

\clearpage %(required for 1-page abstract)
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working!